# Reference for common Typescript types in an Angular/Ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, angular

I'm working on my first Ionic (based on Angular 1.x) Typescript project.  I'm finding that I'm spending way too much time looking around for the right type names to use for the various services, providers, etc.

I know that I can load up the actual `.d.ts` files themselves and inspect them (or, play around with Intellisense) to find the right types.  However, it would be a whole lot easier to just glance at a cheat sheet/quick reference that looks something like the following:

```
Angular
$rootScope: angular.IRootScopeService
$scope: ng.IScope
$state: ng.ui.IStateProvider
$timeout: ng.ITimeoutService

Ionic
$ionicModal: ionic.modal.IonicModalService
$ionicLoading: ionic.loading.IonicLoadingService
$ionicPlatform: ionic.platform.IonicPlatformService

Cordova

etc.
```

Does such a reference exist?  Or, could someone who is a bit more experienced than I throw together a quick guide?  It would be immensely helpful for Typescript newcomers as the "language" becomes more mainstream.

Comment: I think you can give a bounty to this question i am also struggling in this